# Resultado de un Ciclo FOR

Tags: c#, bucle-for

necesito saber qué función cumple la variable línea dentro de un for?

```
salario = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Por favor, Ingresar los salarios de los operarios");
                string linea = Console.ReadLine();
                salario [i] = int.Parse(linea);
            }
```

Comment: que lenguaje?..

Comment: Estoy trabajando el lenguaje C#

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que son enteros

```
int[] salario = new int[5];
```

Lo que hace es capturar un dato a la vez  `string linea = Console.ReadLine();` como cadena `String`
y la otra línea la almacena en el array `salario [i] = int.Parse(linea)`; como entero `Int`

Se puede ejecutar el código aquí en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/DarlingBleakDeclaration)